# What is the smallest Windows header I can #include to define DWORD?

Tags: c, windows, header

I have a small header file of my own which declares a couple of functions, one of which has a return type of `DWORD`.  I'm reluctant to drag in `windows.h` just to get the official definition of this type since that file is huge, and my header will be used in a number of source modules that don't otherwise need it.

Of course, in practice I know that `DWORD` is just `unsigned int`, but I'd prefer the more hygienic approach of including an official header file if possible.

On [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx) it says that `DWORD` is defined in `windef.h`, but unfortunately including just this small file directly leads to compilation errors -- apparently it expects to be included by other headers.  (Also, the fact that my file is a header file also means I can't just declare `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, since the source file that #includes my file might need this to be left undefined.)

Any ideas?  I know it's not the end of the world -- I can just continue to `#include <windows.h>` -- but thought someone might have a better idea!

**[EDIT]**
Thanks for your responses.  To those who suggested using a different type, let me explain why that's not desirable in this case: I've set up different, platform-specific versions of the two functions in different source files, and ask the CMake configuration to detect the current platform and choose which one to build.  On Windows, my functions look like:

```
typedef DWORD TimePoint;
TimePoint GetTimeNow(void);
double TimeDifference(TimePoint start, TimePoint end);
```

The Windows version of `GetTimeNow()` just calls the Windows API `timeGetTime()`, which has return type `DWORD`, and so it must have the same return type.  (On other platforms, `TimePoint` will have a different type, e.g. `struct timeval` on UNIXy platforms.)  In effect, values of type `TimePoint` are opaque, and the only thing you can do with them is pass two of them to `TimeDifference()` to measure the elapsed time between them in seconds.  This enables cross-platform development.  Unfortunately it still means that client code has to know the concrete type of `TimePoint`.

Comment: Why not use the C standard lib, which is avaibale on Windows (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28VS.80%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4ddyt9h%28VS.80%29.aspx ); if all you need is 1-second resolution, there already is a cross-platform version of `TimeDifference()` called `difftime()`

Comment: Thanks Cristoph, in fact that's exactly what I had, but this is for profiling and we have several datasets that take in the 1-10s range so I decided I wanted a bit more resolution.

Answer (score 6):

Include Windows.h and use precompiled headers. Btw, you can define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN and then undef it later!

Comment: Precompiled headers is a good idea, but I'm worried that including windows.h with WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN defined before later including it without might cause the latter #include to be ignored due to #include guards.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you used to be able to include winbase.h, but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore. All of the sources I've seen recommend windows.h, with the option of WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN. As you've indicated, the latter optimization doesn't help you.

You could do something like this.

```
#ifndef _WINDEF_
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
#endif
```

Not clean, but efficient. This typedef isn't likely to ever change.

Answer (score 5):

`Use this file:`
`include <IntSafe.h>`

Answer (score 4):

A `DWORD` is always going to be a 32-bit unsigned int, so it doesn't really matter whether you use `DWORD` or `unsigned long` or `uint32_t`.  If all three types refer to a 32-bit unsigned int, the compiler is going to consider them equivalent.

Since this is part of the platform-specific files, I don't think you need to worry about portability so much.  Heck, dig into the headers to find the native type of a `DWORD` and just put that typedef in your header.  C compilers accept duplicate typedefs as long as they have the same underlying type.

Comment: Actually that's not a bad idea: Windows is constrained from ever changing the type of `DWORD` for compatibility reasons, so I might as well dig up that type and use it directly.

Comment: Isn't uint32_t portable speak for unsigned 32 bit entity?  Ack, call me thread necro...  Why did this pop up as a new questuin? :(

Answer (score 3):

How about - `#include <minwindef.h>`?

Comment: Have you tried this?  (That is, successfully compiled a short program that `#include`s this and contains, e.g., `sizeof(DWORD)`.)  Googling suggests that it `#define`s a `max` macro, which is annoying but not a dealbreaker if it can be turned off!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: just define `NOMINMAX`. IMO, every project should by default define `NOMINMAX` and `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` unless you specifically need those features.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Thanks, it sounds like `NOMINMAX` turns off the `max` name pollution. But `max` was just something I happened to come across, and maybe there are also other surprises defined somewhere inside `minwindef.h`, which require their own `NOTHIS` and `NOTHAT` #defines to be turned off. (Even groveling through the header files isn't a complete solution, since they may change across Windows versions...) I was trying to create an unopinionated library, hence my desire not to specify (or require the absence of) `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: fair point. Either way, it turned out that including `minwindef.h` is problematic, it probably isn't meant to be be included by users, it's an internal Windows SDK header. `IntSafe.h` does work, that's probably the best option.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say to just define it yourself. That way, it's more platform-independent (of course, I don't know if the rest of the code requires Windows). If you don't want to do that, use precompiled headers.

Comment: Precompiled headers is a good idea, but in this case it's not more platform-independent to define it myself -- please see my edits in the original question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is there a <wtypes.h> where you're at?  Because in it, I see:

```
#ifndef _DWORD_DEFINED
#define _DWORD_DEFINED
typedef unsigned long DWORD;

#endif // !_DWORD_DEFINED
```

This file is located under "...\VC98\INCLUDE" here.. which is for VC6 so I'd figured it'll be in later versions.

I was after the same thing as the OP and solved it by including the said header.

Comment: Interesting!  That particular `typedef` seems to be wrapped in an `#ifdef !defined(_WIN32) && !defined(_MPPC_)`, which is commented as "The following code is for Win16 only".  So I'm surprised that it works for you...?

Comment: Hmm..  Quick testing showed that `_WIN32` is indeed defined but `_MPPC_` isn't..  I couldn't find any useful information about this macro so I have no idea what it is..  Portability may be an issue and ymmv, but it works here despite that comment..

I also noticed the line following that comment is another level of wrapping that goes `#ifndef WINAPI` with the comment _If not included with 3.1 headers..._, but `WINAPI` isn't defined here unless <windows.h> is included.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried that when your cross-platform program runs on Windows it will load too many Windows DLLs just because your source code had #include <windows.h>, I think you're worrying too much.  Even Notepad has to load half of the known universe, and it has been known to load and execute on occasion.

If you're worried that when other developers use Windows your cross-platform .h file will put a ton of namespace pollution in their compilation environments, I think you're worrying too much.  99.999% of Windows projects already did an #include <windows.h> before they got to your .h file.

Comment: No DLLs will be loaded because I include a header file, so that's not what I'm worried about.  I just wanted a lighter-weight header to reduce compilation time if possible.  I'll try turning on precompiled headers instead, hopefully there won't be any negative interactions with the CMake build system.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you instead define the function to return `int`?   This is a highly portable type and completely divorces your code from <s>the evil empire</s>Microsoft.

Comment: How is replacing "the evil empire" with "Microsoft" relevant to SO in any way?

Comment: I've clarified my question to explain why in this case, I need to return Windows' idea of a `DWORD`. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a DWORD. I have seen too much Windows code that have been ported to other platforms later. Those DWORDs become a real problem when everybody has their own definition for it. I don't think there are any good reasons to use windows specific types in interfaces.

Even if your code will never be ported to any other platform, I still think code should use the native types or your own types (e.g., MyInt32, MyUInt64, etc), but nothing from windows.h.

Comment: I've clarified my question to explain why in this case, I need to return Windows' idea of a `DWORD`.  Thanks anyway :)