# Limit the scope of #include <windows.h>

Tags: c++, windows

**Background:** I want to enable NVIDIA optimus by default. The solution recommended by NVIDIA is to use `extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;`.

Therefore I need `DWORD`to be defined.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473334/what-is-the-smallest-windows-header-i-can-include-to-define-dword) which asks for the minimum header that defines `DWORD` with the best solution being to define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` and still use windows.h or to define it yourself because it is unlikely to change.

In contrast to the mentioned question I have no problem with the size of windows.h in itself (none issue when using precompiled headers). I would however like to avoid to clutter the global namespace with all its types, functions etc. especially since I only need one type for one line of code.

**TLDR:** Is there any way to include the header but have all of its content only available in a limited scope?

Note that you can't simply include the header in a namespace like so:

```
namespace encloseWindowsTypes {
  #include <Windows.h>
  extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}
```

since part of the windows.h relies on previous part of it being defined in global namespace and you would get errors like `` 'div_t': is not a member of '`global namespace'' ``.

Comment: Make an "edge" file (AlbertWindowsEdge.h and AlbertWindowsEdge.cpp) that contains the header, and provides glue routines to the header.  Then your other code only needs to include your edge header and only needs to use your exposed API.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just use `typedef unsigned long DWORD;`?  Or just declare `NvOptimusEnablement ` as an `unsigned long`?

Comment: "*I only need one type for one line of code*" - then you are best off simply defining `DWORD` yourself where needed, or even not use it at all. `DWORD` is just an alias for `unsigned long`, or if you are paranoid about `long` being different sizes in different compilers/platforms, use `uint32_t` instead as `DWORD` is [formally defined by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types) as "a 32-bit unsigned integer"

Comment: In practice defining it myself is of couse unlikely to cause problems. I was only curious if there is a "cleaner" solution for this, since I have read that it is best practice to use the windows types when programming a piece of code that interacts directly with Microsoft specific functions. The edge file seems to be a nice solution for this type of problem (especially if one had a type that was more likely to change in the future than DWORD).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

Just define it yourself and be done with it:

```
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
```